# Navbar Items get bigger on hover?

Tags: html, css

I've made some changes to some buttons and now my navbar items get bigger on hover, which is a behaviour not desired.

[image]

This behaviour is more noticable when hovering on the logo in the navbar.

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjEMZj

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top navbar-bg">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">&emsp;&emsp;<img src="https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/img/stickers_gallito_logo.png" width="20px" height="30px"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse"
            aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="/stickers">Stickers <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>

        </ul>

        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">

                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/carrito_de_compras/"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"
                                                    style="color:white !important;"></i> ( 3)</a>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true"
                       aria-expanded="false"><i class="fas fa-user-circle"></i> ogonzales</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
                        <a href="/ordenes/historial_de_compras/" class="dropdown-item">Historial de compras</a>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="/salir/">Salir <i class="fas fa-sign-out-alt"></i></a>
                </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: `li.footer_nav_links a:focus, a:hover` means all `a:hover`, not just in `li.footer_nav_links`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the [`footer.css`](https://stickers-gallito-uploaded-files.s3.amazonaws.com/static/css/footer.css) Line #38:

```css
li.footer_nav_links a:focus, a:hover {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(2, 214, 158);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Get rid of the `font-size: 12px` there and it would be fine. Maybe, you are using `a:hover` in a generic way, so it affects all the `<a>` tags when hovered. Did you mean `li.footer_nav_links a:hover`?

```css
li.footer_nav_links a:focus, li.footer_nav_links a:hover {
    font-size: 12px;
    color: rgb(2, 214, 158);
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: but I'm using the `footer_nav_links` on my footer links, and need the 12px font size.

Comment: @OmarGonzales But you are using `a:hover` in a generic way, so it affects all the `<a>` tags when hovered. Did you mean `li.footer_nav_links a:hover`?